# Specifying Encoding While Placing Files In InDesign Using Extendscript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have a script that places a Markdown file into a text frame in InDesign. Unfortunately, InDesign doesn't seem to be picking up on the UTF-8 encoding, as quotation marks and other things are ending up as `‚Äú`.

I tried setting `file.encoding` to `"UTF-8"` based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272770/getting-strange-characters-when-pasting-from-the-clipboard-into-indesign), all to no avail. Here's the relevant code as it stands:

```
var file = File.openDialog ("Select content markdown" , "Markdown:*.md", false );
file.encoding = "UTF-8";
myFirstTextframe.place(file);
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Try to find out what InDesign's automatic file recognition thinks it is: `myFirstTextframe.place(file, true);` will show the Import Text Options.

Comment: @Jongware Hmm. It's saying Macintosh Roman. Manually selecting Unicode UTF8 in that dialog does work, if clumsily.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure (perhaps InDesign is just remembering what I selected in the Import Options window), but it seems like adding this solved my problem:

```
with(app.textImportPreferences){
    characterSet = TextImportCharacterSet.UTF8;
    useTypographersQuotes = true;
}
```